# OnDrawFrame function getting called only once Vuforia AR issue

Tags: android-manifest, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Vuforia to build an AR App but when I add:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file, the camera gets stuck and `OnDrawFrame` gets called only once.
And when I add this tag then I get  a smart terrain initialization error for ground plane while `OnDrawFrame` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolve onDrawFrame not getting called issue by replacing old Vuforia.jar file with latest one. And need to replace com.google.ar:core:1.33.0 with com.google.ar:core:1.22.0 and add
<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional"  in Manifest for solve smart terrain initilization issue